# Frustrated about responsiveness on mobile

Tags: css, iphone, mobile

I believe many of you faced this before. I finished the development of my site. During the development I was using media queries and use Firefox Responsive Design View. I made a research to see what are the most common screen resolution and added those resolutions. Tested too with Chrome and Opera resizing browsers.

Today when I was tested on mobile (Moto G) my site seems to be unresponsive. Their layout didn't changed. One other thing that I did was to use Chrome Developer Tools enabling Device Toolbar. For my surprise any selected device changed my layout.

On media queries I used width min-width and max-width to make adjustments.
Reading on SO I see the most indicated is to use device-width instead of width.

So, do I need to change all my media queries to see results on mobile? Am I lost screen resolution on computers?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't upload the files to your web server? Or if you're using preprocessors and an app for it, maybe it didn't converted your code? Those are just my thoughts, nothing serious.

I'm using this media query for medium screen:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 992px)
```

It's working perfectly for me, and for mobile screen I don't even specify the minimum width.

Anyway, I need code pasted to jsFiddle to help you, thanks.

Comment: For example I use this for screens with a minimum of 900px
media only screen and (min-width: 900px)

And these are my other media queries:
media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width: 414px)
media only screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width: 600px)
media only screen and (min-width:600px) and (max-width: 864px)
media only screen and (min-width:667px) and (max-width: 736px)
media only screen and (width:800px) and (height:600px)

Comment: That's weird. Can you send your website's link via PM or just post it here, so others can see it and help you. And as I said, I would be glad if you would put some code with an example in jsFiddle

Comment: Ok. www.madebyalex.org

Comment: Main solution is to use framework such as bootstrap and re-done the whole website. Otherway would be to not use so many different media queries, because it's really looking bad, e.g. from 881px to 915px, from 683px to 752px and from 0px to 335px it doesnt show up at all. I think the problem is that you use way too many media queries and/or you line up them wrongly.

Comment: I'll not use bootstrap. I did this way to learn. I'm using those media queries based on presents founded on internet and inserted in Firefox developer tools

Comment: What really annoys me is when testing on Firefox using responsive design view my media queries works like a charm. But when I test on chrome it seems like I didn't anything.

Comment: For me, using Firefox your website works same link in Chrome. Maybe you're using some styles that works only in Firefox or only in Chrome? An example would be "-moz-appearance" or similar style, where you use -moz- at the start. I don't know how to help you, because for me, it works same in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

After another research I found out I forgot meta tag viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Adding that solves the problem.